# Problem with transparency in plotting shapes

Tags: pgfplots, transparency, posters, baposter

I am trying to plot shapes with transparency inside a baposter environment, however it does not plot with the transparency. To test this file you will need to also add the baposter class found here - [baposter class file](http://www.brian-amberg.de/uni/poster/baposter/baposter.cls)

```
\documentclass[a0paper,portrait]{baposter}

%%% Global Settings %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% plotting libraries
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

% Color Definitions 
\definecolor{bordercol}{RGB}{40,40,40}
\definecolor{headercol1}{RGB}{255,204,0}
\definecolor{headercol2}{RGB}{255,204,0}
\definecolor{headerfontcol}{RGB}{0,0,0}
\definecolor{boxcolor}{RGB}{255,244,204}

\usepackage{transparent}


% custom packages + macros + definitions

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Document Start %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}


%%% General Poster Settings %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%% Eye Catcher, Title, Authors and University Images %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{poster}{
    grid=false,
    columns=2,
    % Option is left on true though the eyecatcher is not used. The reason is
    % that we have a bit nicer looking title and author formatting in the headercol
    % this way
    %eyecatcher=false, 
    borderColor=bordercol,
    headerColorOne=headercol1,
    headerColorTwo=headercol2,
    headerFontColor=headerfontcol,
    % Only simple background color used, no shading, so boxColorTwo isn't necessary
    boxColorOne=boxcolor,
    headershape=smallrounded,
    headerfont=\Large\sf\bf,
    textborder=none,
    background=none,
    headerborder=none,
  boxshade=plain
}

%%% Title %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
{\sf\bf
    Example
}
%%% Authors %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
{
    \vspace{1em} A.B. C\\
}

\headerbox{Transparent Plot}{name=intro,column=0,row=0}{
    \begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[ 
     axis x line=bottom, axis y line=left,
     title=Localisation Technologies Comparison,
     xmin=-2, xmax=2,
     ymin=-2, ymax=2,
     xtick={-2,-1,0,1,2},
     ytick={-2,-1,0,1,2},
     xlabel=Accuracy, ylabel=Coverage,
     axis background/.style={fill=white}
     ] 
      \fill[red] (0,0) rectangle (1,0.5);
      \fill[fill opacity=0.7] (0.5,0) rectangle (1.5,0.25);

    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
}


\end{poster}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: do you still have this problem? I can't replicate it via any PDF reader. Looks like a viewer problem to me